# Sort sorted matrix

Tags: ds.algorithms, matrices, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good special-case sorting algorithm?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-a-good-special-case-sorting-algorithm)

Is there any linear-time sorting algorithm for sorting elements of a sorted matrix (a matrix with all rows and columns sorted)?

Comment: What do you mean? Do we start with each row sorted in increasing order? Or each column? Or both? If so, what does the algorithm need to do?

Comment: This seems to be an elementary/homework-level question. @mehas: could you please provide some motivation and explain why you are interested in this question?

Comment: Seems to me like a special case of merge sort...

Comment: @Kaveh I became interested about this question after

Comment: @Anthony Labarre. Each column and row are sorted.
@Kaveh I became interested about this question because of another problem: given element X, you need to find this element in such a matrix (This is easy). One variant of solution was to make an linear sorted array from that matrix and perform a binary search over it. I became interested about this task and asked the question here.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito
Thank you! This is exactly what I tried to find.

Comment: I can remember having this as homework assignment.